# Linux console periodically hangs for sporadic, short periods of time

Tags: linux, console

I am working with embedded Linux, and I have some strange behavior on custom board, in which the serial console—connection via UART—hangs for a 1-2 seconds every 15-20 seconds: The entered chars in console are echoes right after this hang is over. It is as if it is busy in doing something. 
Additional info: when using nfs there is no such issue, only when using rootfs (jffs) from nand.
Does any one have any idea what might cause such behavior and how to check the root cause of this?

Comment: Hi Jake, I'm connecting over serial (UART)

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what kind of custom system you are using, but according [to this site](http://pcduino.com/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=9d1ed2148e9e310e35711aa205da2009&topic=3951.msg5045#msg5045) a similar issue is caused by a bug in the UART driver. The solution is to update/patch the driver.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was jffs thread getting high cpu resourse (80%) every ~60 second (there was some random timing of this to happen), on moving to ubifs, it been solved.